# Highlight Hash Tag using At.js?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, laravel

I am trying to make **Hash Tag** functionality using **At.js**. 
For now using the static data, dropping down successfully.
I need to **Highlight** the hashtag with different color and font weight.
Code is:

**Headers:**

```
<link href="css/jquery.atwho.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.caret.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.atwho.js"></script>
```

**TextBox** (*for creating the hashtag*)

```
<input type="text"  id="questionName" name="questionName" style="color: #3A404C  !important;"  placeholder="Type here" class="span11 QuestionBox"/>
```

**At.js function**

```
$('#questionName').atwho({
at: "#",

data:["Boston", "Chicago", "Miami", "Orlando", "Atlanta", "Philadelphia", "NewYork", "Indiana", "Charlotte", "Milwaukee", "Detroit", "NewJersey", "Toronto", "Washington", "Cleveland"]

})
```

Thank You !